# reading the version prefix from an external file instead of the .csproj file

Tags: linux, msbuild, csproj, .net-core-2.0

At this time, my .csproj files contain the XPath `/Project/PropertyGroup/VersionPrefix` and that determines the version for the nuget packages.
However, I would prefer to read this version prefix from a shared file, as it will be common for 3 or 4 projects, each of whom have their own .csproj files.

In other words, instead of having

`<VersionPrefix>2.0.0</VersionPrefix>`

we would prefer to have something like

`@@include ../../version.xml`

and this version.xml contains the line above which will be substituted.

I am sure there would be multiple ways to achieve this but cannot fathom exactly how. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a file named `Directory.Build.props` in the folder hierarchy above all your projects (e.g. next to the solution file) and put shared properties in there:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>2.0.0</VersionPrefix>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

MSBuild will automatically find and import this file. (you may need to re-open your editor / visual studio). See MSBuild's [Customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build) documentation for more information.